# Formatting data to a thermal printer via fwrite

Tags: php, printing, formatting, fwrite, thermal-printer

The project is to print some order details to the thermal printer for a customer using PHP.

I have successfully installed via USB the EPSON TM-T88V thermal printer on my Windows 10, running on localhost with WAMP, the below code works like a charm:

```
<?php
$printer = "\\\\localhost\\TM-T88V";

$fp = fopen($printer, "w");
if (!$fp) {
    die('no connection');
}

$data = " 123456789 ";

if (!fwrite($fp, $data)) {
    die('writing failed');
}
```

Is there a way to format the data, before sending them for printing? Like break-line, margins, bold, borders etc.. ?

I don't want to use any other library or class or whatever. I want to keep it simple with fopen and fwrite just like the example. Also the printer will always be the same.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [The official webpage](http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/jsp/Product.do?sku=C31CA85011#EpsonTechnology) mentions it uses ESC/POS protocol. [This](https://mike42.me/blog/what-is-escpos-and-how-do-i-use-it) should be useful.